# iOS: Can I tell if a user has opted-out of Apple's "Share With App Developers" setting?

Tags: ios, analytics, privacy

We use a third-party analytics library in our app. I'd like to automatically opt users out of these analytics if they have the **Privacy > Analytics > Share With App Developers** switch turned off.

I understand that this is only for opting users out of Apple forwarding on the analytics they collect, but I feel the intention is clear: that the user doesn't want the developer to receive analytics, no matter the source.

Is there an API to check for this setting or is the only option to re-prompt the user in the app as to whether they want to send analytics?

For that matter is there a way to detect if the user has opted out of all analytics? The intention is less clear here as the description specifically says "Help Apple improve" but again it feels a little weird to prompt the user to send analytics if they've opted out at this level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an API to check for this setting or is the only option to re-prompt the user in the app as to whether they want to send analytics?

No, Apple doesn't share any information related to user privacy.

---

Firstly I think that we, all the developers, need these Analytics, User Engagement & Crash Logs.

Having said that no App/Developer should ever violate the rights of user. 
There comes [Apple Privacy Policy](https://www.apple.com/in/legal/privacy/en-ww) to get user permission for [Apple App Analytics](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/analytics/) to be sent to the App Developers enrolled in Apple Developer Program. But that's just Apple taking care of their legalities. As a developer, we should abide by the legal policies of our Company and abide by the App Store policies and policies of any third party libraries we are using in our app.

For example:

1. Your App/Company must have a Privacy Policy page & Terms & Condition Page which you give to Apple in the iTunesConnect before uploading the App. So, when the user is downloading the App, he/she has to agree to them.
2. You are using Crashlytics in your app. You should abide by https://firebase.google.com/terms/crashlytics.

Reference for more reading: [How to make your App's privacy policy complaint to data protection and privacy laws](https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/crashlytics-privacy-policy/)